# How to get the nth element of an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Supposing I have the following javascripts inserted in my HTML code...

```
<a href="http://example.com" data-example="my example">Example #1</a>
<script src="http://example.com/javascript.js"></script>

<a href="http://example.com" data-example="my example">Example #2</a>
<script src="http://example.com/javascript.js"></script>

<a href="http://example.com" data-example="my example">Example #3</a>
<script src="http://example.com/javascript.js"></script>
```

How do I get the value of **data-example** in the 3rd link (Example #3)?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('a')[2].dataset.example` is one way in pure JS

Comment: It's very easy to write the code if you have a static or constant index number of the array.. But what if you don't.. like `document.querySelectorAll('a')[n].dataset.example`

Comment: All of the answers given below are also based on static markup/array index number. That is what your question specifically asks. If it is not static then you need some method other than an index to be able to find what you are looking for, the same with all the answers below. So what is it you really want?

Comment: Yes you should specify in your question if the content is static or dynamic. Provide static content, and you will get a static answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use **[eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)**. `Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.`

```
$('a[data-example]').eq(2).text();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfgpehzp/2/)**

Comment: The way I read, the OP wants the value of the `data-example` attribute. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var data = $('a:eq(2)').data('example');
```

See [:eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [psuedo selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp). [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/96nc80qw/)

```
$('a:nth-of-type(3)').data('example')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to rely on "*getting all the anchors that have `data-example` on it*", but doing something more explicitly, like specifying a `class` for these links:

```
<a class="my-link" href="http://example.com" data-example="my example">Example #1</a>
<script src="http://example.com/javascript.js"></script>

<a class="my-link" href="http://example.com" data-example="my example">Example #2</a>
<script src="http://example.com/javascript.js"></script>

<a class="my-link" href="http://example.com" data-example="my example">Example #3</a>
<script src="http://example.com/javascript.js"></script>
```

And then, using jQuery

```
 $(".my-link:eq(3)").data("example")
```

Why the suggestion? because you might later have other links with `data-example` too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the value of `data-example` attribute, you can use `:before` or `:after` pseudo class in CSS.

```
a:before {
    content: attr(data-example);
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/dk8benas/)

Answer (score 0):

Here a generally usable function for this purpose.

```
function getEqData(selector, data, num){
    return $(selector).eq(num-1).data(data);
}

var data = getEqData('a', 'example', 3);
console.log(data);
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a30fvhta/)**